# Pre-Deployment script is not included into publishing script

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I inherited database project.

it has a lot of create statements for tables and st procedures.
and for some reason all tables without foreign keys.

So I'm creating foreign keys for tables and when I publish I see that `ALTER TABLE` is generated
but data is not clean so it generates an error during the publishing.

I found that I can have Pre-Deployment script (Build Action= PreDeploy)
so I added there a line to support foreign key

```
delete from [AccountBalance] where UserId not in (select userid from [user])
```

but when I generate publishing script it is not there.

Why?

**Update**
Sending Project Code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <SSDTExists Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets')">True</SSDTExists>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(SSDTExists)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <IncludeSchemaNameInFileName>False</IncludeSchemaNameInFileName>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <UpgradedFromDBP>True</UpgradedFromDBP>
    <Name>dbpProjectName</Name>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectVersion>4.1</ProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{f43cbd44-bbab-48f6-949d-47c9042bb406}</ProjectGuid>
    <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql100DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
    <OutputType>Database</OutputType>
    <RootPath>
    </RootPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <UpgradedFromDBP>True</UpgradedFromDBP>
    <RootNamespace>dbpProjectName</RootNamespace>
    <PostUpgradeAddToSCC>;C:\Users\travis\Documents\FR\Projects\Fr\Trunk\Fr.Database\Fr.Database.sqlproj;C:\Users\travis\Documents\FR\Projects\Fr\Trunk\Fr.Database\Connections.txt</PostUpgradeAddToSCC>
    <SccProvider>
    </SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>
    </SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>
    </SccLocalPath>
    <SccProjectName>
    </SccProjectName>
    <UpgradedFromDBP>True</UpgradedFromDBP>
    <AssemblyName>dbpProjectName</AssemblyName>
    <ModelCollation>1033, CI</ModelCollation>
    <DefaultFileStructure>BySchemaAndSchemaType</DefaultFileStructure>
    <DeployToDatabase>True</DeployToDatabase>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetLanguage>CS</TargetLanguage>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <SqlServerVerification>False</SqlServerVerification>
    <TargetDatabaseSet>True</TargetDatabaseSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- VS10 without SP1 will not have VisualStudioVersion set, so do that here -->
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Integration|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties" />
    <Folder Include="Cleanup Scripts" />
    <Folder Include="Pre-Deploy" />
    <Folder Include="Post-Deploy" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Change Scripts" />
    <Folder Include="Create Scripts" />
    <Folder Include="Data" />
    <Folder Include="Functions" />
    <Folder Include="Queries" />
    <Folder Include="Views" />
    <Folder Include="Properties" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\AccountBalance.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\AccountTransaction.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\ActivityType.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Bl.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Butter.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\ButterStash.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\ButterTransfer.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\City.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Contact.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Fan.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Friend.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Fr.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\FrLevel.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\FrLevelQuestion.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\FrLevelQuestionResult.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\FrLevelStatus.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\FrMessage.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\FrPlayer.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\FrPlayerStatus.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\FrQuestion.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\FrStatus.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Invite.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\InviteSource.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\InviteType.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Lookup.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Message.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\MessageActivity.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\MessageRecipient.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\MessageType.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\PasswordReset.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Prize.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\PrizeType.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\TransactionType.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\User.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\UserActivity.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\UserAlternateCountryRequest.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\UserLogin.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\UserMedia.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\UserValidation.sql" />
    <NotInBuild Include="Data\ActivityType.sql" />
    <NotInBuild Include="Data\ButterValues.sql" />
    <NotInBuild Include="Data\CityValues.sql" />
    <NotInBuild Include="Data\LookupValues.sql" />
    <NotInBuild Include="Data\User_TestData.sql" />
    <Build Include="Functions\fn_GetDisplayName.sql" />
    <Build Include="Functions\fn_ListToTable.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\AccountBalanceGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\AccountTransactionCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\AccountTransactionHasCreditPurchase.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\BlCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\BlGetLatest.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\BlsGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\ButterGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\ButterGetAll.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\ButterMostPopularGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\ButterStashCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\ButterStashDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\ButterStashGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\ButterTransferCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\ButterTransferGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\CitySearchByName.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FanCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FanDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FanSearch.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FansGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FansOfUserGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FansOfUserSearch.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FriendCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FriendDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FriendSearch.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FriendSearchByName.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FriendsGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrGetAll.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrGetLevelExpired.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrLevelCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrLevelGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrLevelIsComplete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrLevelQuestionClear.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrLevelQuestionCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrLevelQuestionResultUpsert.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrLevelStatusUpdate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrLevelUpdate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrMessageCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrMessageDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrMessageGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrMessagesGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrPlayerAdd.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrPlayerRemove.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrPlayerUpdate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrQuestionGetAll.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrStart.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrUpdate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrUpdateFringle.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\InviteCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\InviteDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\InviteDeleteByUserId.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\InviteGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\InviteGetAll.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\InviteGetByFrId.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\InviteGetByUserId.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\InviteGetSentAll.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\InviteUpdateAssociateEmailToUserId.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\InviteUpdateInviteStatus.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\InviteUpdateUserId.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\LookupsGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\MessageCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\MessageDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\MessageGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\MessageRecipientActionUpdate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\MessageRecipientUpdate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\MessagesGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\MessagesGetSent.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\MessageThreadGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\MessageUnreadCountGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\PasswordResetCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\PasswordResetDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\PasswordResetGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\PrizeGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\PrizesGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserActivityCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserActivityForRelatedUsersGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserActivityGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserAlternateCountryRequestCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserBrowse.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserFrNameExists.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserGetByEmail.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserHasBeenFrer.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserLoginInsert.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserMediaDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserMediaGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserMediaList.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserMediaUpsert.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserPasswordUpdate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserProfileGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserProfileUpdate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserSearch.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserUpdate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserValidationGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserValidationGetByUserId.sql" />
    <Build Include="Views\UserSummaryView.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\MessageTypeGroup.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\MessageTypeGroup.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserGetByFbId.sql" />
    <PreDeploy Include="Pre-Deploy\Script.PreDeployment1.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Data\Prize.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\PrizeType.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\TransactionType.sql" />
    <None Include="Cleanup Scripts\CleanFrRelatedTables.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\FrLevelStatus.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\FrPlayerStatus.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\FrQuestion.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\FrStatus.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\InviteSource.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\InviteType.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\MessageActivity.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\MessageType.sql" />
    <None Include="Data\FrReminderTypeValues.sql" />
    <None Include="Fr.DevDatabase.publish.xml" />
    <None Include="Fr.IntegrationDatabase.publish.xml" />
    <None Include="Pre-Deploy\Script1.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Feedback.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FeedbackCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\FrReminder.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\FrReminderType.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrReminderCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrReminderUpdate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrReminderDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrReminderUpdateUserId.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrReminderGetPendingWarnings.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\FrReminderGetPendingExpiries.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\BlsFromFriendsGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\Counter.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\CounterGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\CounterSet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserActivityHide.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\BlDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Create Scripts\UserBl.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserBlGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserBlCreate.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\UserBlDelete.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\BlGet.sql" />
    <Build Include="Queries\AccountTransactionGetByFr.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <RefactorLog Include="Fr.Database.refactorlog" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Why this is failing wouldn't be clear unless you shared out your .sqlproj file or gave more information. I tried to reproduce this by creating a project with the tables and predeployment script you show here, and the predeployment script was successfully included in the publish script. Can you re-check the build action and ensure the project file is saved? PreDeployment scripts should always be included when publishing so it's not obvious what's going wrong here

Comment: The project file looks OK, and I tried to reproduce with the same folder structure as your project, but still can't find what's wrong. Some thoughts:
- One version of SSDT released last year had a problem where part of the generated pre-deployment script was lost in some builds. Update to latest.
- Try to verify that the predeployment script in the generated dacpac contains the predeploy script. Go to $(ProjectName)\bin\Debug\ProjectName.dacpac - rename it to .zip and extract the contents. The "predeploy.sql" file should contain all predeployment scripts. If it's missing, something is wrong

Answer (score 3):

You know what...

This is probably NOT your problem but I just got stumped by this for about 20 mins and it turns out that the stupid thing (VS) doesn't apply these things outside of an ACTUAL BUILD (so it must take the build scripts "by convention" and just add them into the publish script automagically...

So if you're like me and until now didn't really grok the importance of the "Configuration Manager" then you may not have noticed that for some reason your item (dtabase project) wasn't checked for "BUILD" in this configuration (DEBUG/RELEASE) then the script will be generated but the pre/post deployment scripts aren't included...

all you get in the output window is "skipped" message which is easy to miss if you have a lot of other projects in the solution!

Anyway just posting this because it might help someone.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Updates to the predeployment script did not get pushed to the published script. REbuilding the project and/or updating the build configuration fixed this for me.